# How to split a column containing two records separately

Tags: awk

I have millions of observation in different columns and one of the column contains records of two factors together. for instance, 136789 and i want to split the first character (1) and the rest (36789) as separate columns for all observations.

The field looks like this

```
#136789
```

I want to see like this

```
#1   36789
```

Comment: Provide a sample input file and an expected output file.

Comment: Update the sample file in the question for reference to everyone referring

Comment: @Are there further columns after this? (and) are there columns before this? How do you expect it to be identified if it is in middle?

Comment: @Inian I have  20 columns and the column that i want to split is at column 19.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `sub()` function.

For example:

```
kent$ awk 'BEGIN{x="123456";sub(/^./,"& ",x);print x}' 
1 23456
```

In your code,  you need apply `sub()` on some column (`$x`)

Comment: the column ($17) i want to split is at the end of other columns. so how can i write the script?

Comment: `awk '{sub(/^./,"& ",$17)}7' file` @Alula